# How do I handle multiple notification of ReadDirectoryChangesW()?

Tags: readdirectorychangesw

I implemented using ReadDirectoryChangesW() function to figure out any change information of files of the specific directory.

However, the API sent me duplicated notifications. For example, I monitor the directory "C:\abc\" using only FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE flag without watching subdirectory. And, I tried edit and save a image file on the directory. ex) C:\abc\imageFile.png

Then, two or much more the notifications were sent me. Actually, I understand why there are multiple notifications. I read this article. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/05/07/10523172.aspx)
But, I don't know how to handle the multiple notifications.

My goal is synchronizing the image files on some win32 application when the images are changed.

Comment: ReadDirectoryChangesW tells you [when the result of a "dir" has changed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/12/10195186.aspx). It is not for detecting when a file is modified. For that, you need to use the change journal.

Comment: I know the ReadDirectoryChangesW() tell me the changes of 'dir'. But, We can figure out what a file was changed from 'lpBuffer' parameter of the API. The parameter can be casting to FILE_NOTIFICATION_INFORMATION structure.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` tells us:

> *NextEntryOffset*
>   The number of bytes that must be skipped to get to the next record. **A value of zero indicates that this is the last record.**

So we check that field, and if it isn't zero, we create a new pointer which is that many bytes past the old one.  The code will look something like this:

```
FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* p = &s.changeInformation;
while (1) {
    std::wcout << L"    action " << p->Action << L"\n";
    std::wcout << L"    file ";
    std::wcout.write(p->FileName, p->FileNameLength / sizeof (wchar_t)) << L"\n";
    if (!p->NextEntryOffset) break;
    p = reinterpret_cast<decltype(p)>(p->NextEntryOffset + reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p));
}
```

We have to cast, because the value is in bytes, and pointer arithmetic automatically measures distances in objects not bytes.